# linked lists vs arrays: which is more contiguous in physical memory?

Tags: arrays, c, caching, memory

Arrays are not necessarily contiguous in physical memory, though they are contiguous in virtual address space. But can it be said that the "tidiness" of arrays in physical memory is significantly higher compared to linked lists? So, which is a better option for a cache-friendly program?

Comment: I think this question focuses on one problem only!

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why contiguous memory is more cache-friendly than non-contiguous memory:

1. If the data is stored contiguously, then the data will likely be stored in less [cache lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entries) (which are 64 byte blocks on most platforms). In that case, there is a higher chance that all the data will fit in the cache and new cache lines will less often have to be loaded. If the data is not stored contiguously and is scattered in many random memory locations, then it is possible that only a small fraction of every cache line will contain important data and that the rest of the cache line will contain unimportant data. In that case, more cache lines would be required to cache all important data, and if the cache is not large enough to store all these cache lines, then the cache efficiency will decrease.
2. The hardware [cache prefetcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_prefetching) will do a better job at predicting the next cache line to prefetch, because it is easy to predict a sequential access pattern. Depending on whether the elements of the linked list are scattered or not, the access pattern to a linked list may be random and unpredictable, whereas the access pattern to an array is often sequential.

You are right that even if an array is stored contiguously in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), this does not necessarily mean that the array is also contiguously in the physical address space.

However, this is irrelevant with regard to my statements made in #1 of my answer), because a cache line cannot overlap the boundary of a [memory page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)). The content of a single memory page is always contiguous, both in the virtual address space and in the physical address space.

But you are right that it can be relevant with regard to my statements made in #2 of my answer. Assuming a memory page size of 4096 bytes (which is standard on the x64 platform) and a cache line size of 64 bytes, then there are 64 cache lines per memory page. This means that every 64<sup>th</sup> cache line could be at the edge of a "jump" in the physical address space. As a result, every 64<sup>th</sup> cache line could be mispredicted by the hardware cache prefetcher. Also, the cache prefetcher may not be able to adapt itself immediately to this new situation, so it may fail to prefetch several cache lines before it is able to reliably predict the next cache lines again and preload them in time. However, as a application programmer, you should not have to worry about this. It is the responsibility of the operating system to arrange the mapping of the virtual memory space to the physical memory space in such a way that there are not too many "jumps" which could have a negative performance impact. If you want to read more on this topic, you might want to read this research paper: [Analysis of hardware prefetching across virtual page boundaries](http://tnm.engin.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/353/2017/12/2007.07.Analysis_of_hardware_prefetching.pdf)

Generally, arrays are better than linked lists in terms of cache efficiency, because they are always contiguous (in the virtual address space).